# How do I shrink a div?

Tags: html, css, canvas, layout

I'm having a frustrating time with HTML and CSS.

Basically, I'm trying to make a website with a layout like

[image]

Problem is, the div on the left has a massive margin, which displaces the canvas and makes happen.

[image]

I've tried all kinds of solutions of which here are some, with the problems they caused:

Setting the div's display to inline block. This made the div dissapear entirely for some reason, and made it's contents appear to the right of the canvas. (At least it moved the canvas up). I have to point out that the contents weren't actually visible. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> said they were there`.

Changing the div to an inline component (`span`). Made no difference.

I tried `margin: 0px;`. This didn't change it at all. `margin-left and margin-right` to auto just centred the div and didn't move the canvas.

I tried setting manual `width/height` values for the div. No difference.

There are some solutions that I think are likely to work, but I am reluctant to try them.

I could make a table and add the elements into it, but I heard this is bad practice and would like to avoid it.

I could maually set the positions, but I fear that they might change across devices and resolutions.

I'm at a bit of a loss what to do. I am a beginner at HTML and layouting in general, so please excuse me if it's something really obvious I'm missing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why not using bootstrap? it's very easy and you can make it with simple "col" classes. Check bootstrap's grid bro https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: ^bootstrap is bloated and what you are asking can be accomplished with relatively little code HOWEVER you're going to have to post some code for us to help you.

Comment: ^Thanks, I would have, but float:left; solved my problem. I'm a massive idiot. I thought float:left; only applied to moving things around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really "shrinking" you're after. But since I don't know what you're calling your divs and canvas, I'll give you the general solution.
-> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp
So basically try adding this:

```
div, canvas {
  float: left;
}
```

Assuming your div and canvas is a `<div></div>` and `<canvas></canvas>`, and that you haven't added a `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` to any of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I can't believe I'm such an idiot.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck on your project!